# flex duct work with K&T

Tags: central-heating

Can I run flex ductwork in a floor joist with coated knob and tube in good condition.
the length of the run will be 2 feet. trying to get the register to be under the cabinets instead of the floor.

Comment: I would be nervous as all get out with knob and tube in my home.  Personally I would put all my resources toward replacing it.

Comment: In what way is the duct work "with" the K&T wiring?